# Is there a module like "Eclipse Resources Project"

Tags: intellij-idea

I have some eclipse projects which have a bunch of text/excel/etc files.
It's not a Java or some other programming language project.

This is called "Resources project" in Eclipse.

But I can't create this kind module in IntelliJ IDEA.

If it's not a kine of specific IntelliJ IDEA module, IDEA does not import this as a module.

Is this possible to create a module like Eclipse Resources project?

Comment: What is it used for? Do you "build" it and produce some kind of artifact? Like a zip or anything the like? If you don't produce anything then what is the purpose of it?

Comment: @maba Because I want to edit, version control and etc with a same tool which is used for programming. Then I don't need to leave my IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Java module with no code inside. Then remove unnecessary stuff from that module and it will behave like a "Resource" project.

I started by creating an empty project:

[image]

Then I created a new Java Module called `Documents`:

[image]

Then press `Finish` to get back to the editor.

Now open up the `Module Settings` and unmark the `src` folder as being a source folder:

[image]

Moreover markt the `Module SDK` to be `<No Project SDK>`:

[image]

Then I finally remove the `src` folder since it is not needed (no sources, just doucuments):

[image]

Now you have a fully functional "Document" module that never gets compiled and can be part of the source control.

[image]

---

You are still able to add code modules alongside with the `Documents` module be it Python, Java or whatever you want.

Of course you don't have to have an empty project from the beginning, you can just add the module I showed to an existing Java project for example.